# Can I run NoteTab clips from the command line?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing HTML documentation and sometimes need to update the "master" CSS and then run a batch file in Windows to copy the updated CSS files to the various doc projects. Then I use clips in NoteTab Light to tweak the CSS for this doc or that in specific places. I'm looking for a way to execute a clip in NoteTab from the command line to go something like:

open NoteTab > open doc1.css > execute Clip1 > save doc1.css

after I run the batch file. Ideas?